# How to calculate a the PFE for a Swaption?

Tags: options, swaps, cva, counterparty-risk

How do you calculate the [Potential Future Exposure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potential_future_exposure) (PFE) for a swaption?

Do you incorporate the dynamics of implied volatility when you are running your simulations?

Is there a standard way to model the real-world joint dynamics of rates and volatilitiess?

Comment: What do you mean by PFE? Please be specific and include links for definitions if possible.

Comment: By PFE I mean potential future exposure. pls see eg. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potential_future_exposure